# Stuck in recovery after CF root

Tags: rooting, samsung

I tried rooting my Samsung Galaxy J3 and now it says:

> "recovery is not seandroid enforcing"

I used CF root and now it wont boot out of recovery.

How do I repair?

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced that before, 2 times ( one with CWM and one with TWRP). I fixed it by:-

1. Pulling out the battery, re-insert it, and boot into download mode
   (vol up + power button + home button).
2. Use Odin (if you don't have one, download it [here](http://odindownload.com))
3. Download the stock firmware for your specific device [here](http://sammobile.com/firmwares)
4. Once your stock firmware finished downloading, head over to Odin and click AP. Browse for the stock firmware you've downloaded and
   click OK.
5. Connect your phone to your computer and click start at Odin.
6. Wait for a couple of minutes, and there you go! You fixed your phone.

Hope this helps.